# Generating data for a CBOW model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, word2vec, word-embedding

I cant figure out how to build a tensorflow word embedding CBOW model.
I have trouble building the generate data function.
This is my preprocessing func:

```
# Removes sentences with fewer than 3 words
corpus = [sentence for sentence in corpus if sentence.count(" ") >= 2]

# remove punctuation in text and fit tokenizer on entire corpus
tokenizer = Tokenizer(filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n'+"'")
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(corpus)

# convert text to sequence of integer values
corpus = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(corpus)
n_samples = sum(len(s) for s in corpus) # total number of words in the corpus
V = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1 # total number of unique words in the corpus
```

I already have Skipgram implemented like so:

```
def generate_data_skipgram(corpus, window_size, V):
    maxlen = window_size*2
    all_in = []
    all_out = []
    for words in corpus:
        L = len(words)
        for index, word in enumerate(words):
            p = index - window_size
            n = index + window_size + 1

            in_words = []
            labels = []
            for i in range(p, n):
                if i != index and 0 <= i < L:
                    # Add the input word
                    #in_words.append(word)
                    all_in.append(word)
                    # Add one-hot of the context words
                    all_out.append(to_categorical(words[i], V))

    return (np.array(all_in),np.array(all_out))
```

How should I approach creating a `generate_data_CBOW` function, similar to the one of the generate skipgram.
I tried looking for something similar but all the results are from 2016 and pretty outdated

EDIT:
This is the model I'm running my skipgram model through, if its any help

```
dim=50
dim1=150
dim2=300
#create skipgram architecture
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=V, output_dim=dim, input_length=1, embeddings_initializer='glorot_uniform', ))
model.add(Reshape((dim,)))
model.add(Dense(V, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='softmax'))
# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
# summarize the model
print(model.summary())
plot_model(model, show_shapes = True, show_layer_names=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def generate_context_word_pairs(corpus, window_size, vocab_size):
    context_length = window_size*2
    for words in corpus:
        sentence_length = len(words)
        for index, word in enumerate(words):
            context_words = []
            label_word   = []            
            start = index - window_size
            end = index + window_size + 1
            
            context_words.append([words[i] 
                                 for i in range(start, end) 
                                 if 0 <= i < sentence_length 
                                 and i != index])
            label_word.append(word)

            x = sequence.pad_sequences(context_words, maxlen=context_length)
            y = np_utils.to_categorical(label_word, vocab_size)
            yield (x, y)


# Test this out for some samples
i = 0
for x, y in generate_context_word_pairs(corpus=wids, window_size=window_size, vocab_size=vocab_size):
    if 0 not in x[0]:
        print('Context (X):', [id2word[w] for w in x[0]], '-> Target (Y):', id2word[np.argwhere(y[0])[0][0]])
    
        if i == 10:
            break
        i += 1
```

[image]